# Construction of a relational database from over 1000 XML files

Tags: r, xml, sqlite, xml-parsing, relational-database

I have around 1000 XML files in a folder. Each file looks something like this.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='anzctrTransform.xsl'?>
<ANZCTR_Trial requestNumber="379991">
  <stage>Registered</stage>
  <submitdate>28/07/2020</submitdate>
  <approvaldate>22/12/2021</approvaldate>
  <dateLastUpdated>22/12/2021</dateLastUpdated>
  <actrnumber>ACTRN12621001757808</actrnumber>
  <trial_identification>
    <studytitle>Symmetry of gait in transfemoral amputees.
</studytitle>
    <scientifictitle>Clinical, biomechanical adaptation of people after unilateral transfemoral amputation or amelia of the lower  limb to gait using advanced prosthetic solutions  - a prospective, single-center, clinical, controlled, observational study.</scientifictitle>
    <utrn />
    <trialacronym />
    <secondaryid>None</secondaryid>
  </trial_identification>
  <conditions>
    <healthcondition>Traumatic amputation at the thigh level</healthcondition>
    <healthcondition>Vascular amputation at thigh level</healthcondition>
    <healthcondition>Congenital defect of the lower limb</healthcondition>
    <healthcondition>Cancer-related amputation</healthcondition>
    <conditioncode>
      <conditioncode1>Physical Medicine / Rehabilitation</conditioncode1>
      <conditioncode2>Physiotherapy</conditioncode2>
    </conditioncode>
    <conditioncode>
      <conditioncode1>Musculoskeletal</conditioncode1>
      <conditioncode2>Other muscular and skeletal disorders</conditioncode2>
    </conditioncode>
  </conditions>
  <interventions>
    <interventions>The bomechanical study will include unilateral tranfemoral amputation patients (UniTransFemorLimLos), who will constitute Group I. Group II will consist of age-matched healthy volunteers. The methodology and parameters of the biomechanical study will be established according to the literature on biomechanical testing. The study will be performed in a certified Biomechanical Analysis Laboratory (PN-EN ISO 9001:2001) using the BTS Smart-E system (BTS Bioengineering, Milan, Italy), which uses six digital infrared cameras (1. 1 µm infrared light, 120 frames per second at 768 x 576 px resolution), two AXIS 210A Network Cams operating in the visible range at 20 Hz and two piezoelectric force plates type 9286A (Kistler Instrumente AG, Winterthur) specifically designed for use in gait analysis with a measurement threshold above 250 mN and a range of 0-5 kN for the vertical component. Data were collected via a digital USB/PC input and processed in the BTS Smart Analyser software. A total of 22 photoreflective markers were placed on the subject's body, following the standard procedure for the Davis model. Hip flexion (FL) and extension (EXT) musculoskeletal speed and endurance abilities were measured using a Biodex System 4 Pro device.  All measurements were performed in the sagittal plane under isokinetic (60°/s and 120°/s angular velocity) and isometric conditions. The following variables were studied: peak torque for FL and EXT under isometric conditions, peak torque for FL and EXT under isokinetic conditions. The torque ratio FL to EXT (F/E ratio) was calculated for the intact and amputated limb. The test is carried out on a one-off basis. The duration of the test is approximately 1.5 h. During the test subjects will be asked to walk a distance of 6 m several times (5 back and forth) in a prosthesis at a freely chosen gait speed.
</interventions>
    <comparator>Observational study. Comparison is being made between patients with lower limb amputation wearing a prosthesis and healthy, age-matched volunteers.</comparator>
    <control>Active</control>
    <interventioncode>Not applicable</interventioncode>
  </interventions>
  <outcomes>
    <primaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Firrs primary outcome is a clinical observation of walking for people after UniTransFemorLimLos. For each participant and each of the measured cycles, time normalization of the right and
left angles for the sagittal plane or GRF components was performed numerically, utilizing decomposition of a time series (trend detection) using the Lagrange interpolation polynomial (MATLAB script). In this way, right and left cycles of the same length (100% Cycle Time (CT) for angles and 100% Stance Time (ST) for GRF components) with discrete values (every 0.5%) were obtained. Gait symmetry was evaluated based on the vertical ground reaction force (vGRF) and the anterior-posterior (a-p GRF) ground reaction force.</outcome>
      <timepoint>Immediately following the test/</timepoint>
    </primaryOutcome>
    <primaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Vertical ground reaction force by means of 2 Kistler 9286A dynamometer platforms running at 1000 Hz. </outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session.</timepoint>
    </primaryOutcome>
    <primaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Anterior-posterior ground reaction force by means of 2 Kistler 9286A dynamometer platforms running at 1000 Hz. </outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </primaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Biomechanical assessment of muscle torque: 
Hip extensor muscle torque measured in Nm.
</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Biomechanical assessment of muscle torque:
Hip flexor muscle torque measured with Nm.
</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Biomechanical assessment of muscle torque:
Hip extensor muscle torque measured with %BW (Body Weight).

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Biomechanical assessment of muscle torque:
Hip flexor muscle torque measured with %BW (Body Weight).

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:pelvic obliquity: upward (positive) or downward (negative) movement of the pelvis in the frontal plane 

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:pelvic tilt: forward (positive) or backward (negative) movement of the pelvis in the sagittal plane; 
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:pelvic rotation: internal (positive) or external (negative) movement of the pelvis in the transverse plane; 
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:hip adduction/adduction: adduction (positive) or adduction (negative) of the femur in the frontal plane; 
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:hip flexion-extension: flexion (positive) or extension (negative) of the femur in the sagittal plane; 
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:hip rotation: internal (positive) or external (negative) movement of the femur in the transverse plane; 
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>
We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:knee flexion-extension: femoral flexion (positive) or extension (negative) in the sagittal plane; 
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:ankle flexion-extension: dorsal (positive) or longitudinal (negative) movement of the foot in the sagittal plane of the foot;
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>We measured time series of variables characterizing motion of the pelvis and major joints of the lower extremities. Following the ISB recommendations for joint coordinate system definitions, the following angles, sampled at 120 Hz and normalized to cycle time (%CT), were selected:and vertical, anteroposterior, and medial-lateral components of ground reaction force (GRF) as a function of standing time (%ST). GRF components were normalized to body weight and expressed as percentages (%BW).
For these data we calculated: Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max, ROM

</outcome>
      <timepoint>During single assessment session</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
  </outcomes>
  <eligibility>
    <inclusivecriteria>Inclusion criteria will include:
1. Loss of lower limb at the level of the thigh.
2. the use of a prosthetic limb in addition to daily living.
3. use of the currently used prosthesis for at least 6 months.
4.The ability to walk a distance of not less than 20 metres without the use of elbow crutches.
5.Congenital lower limb impingement consisting of absence of the knee joint and structures below.
6.Medicare Functional Classification K level 3 or 4.
7.Informed consent for the study.

Key inclusion criteria Healthy, age-matched volunteers: Inclusion criteria will include:
1. No history of musculoskeletal or nervous system disorders on the day of the study.
2. absence of cognitive impairment.

</inclusivecriteria>
    <inclusiveminage>18</inclusiveminage>
    <inclusiveminagetype>Years</inclusiveminagetype>
    <inclusivemaxage>70</inclusivemaxage>
    <inclusivemaxagetype>Years</inclusivemaxagetype>
    <inclusivegender>Both males and females</inclusivegender>
    <healthyvolunteer>Yes</healthyvolunteer>
    <exclusivecriteria>The exclusion criteria will be pain in the stump or lower limbs and chronic diseases that could affect the fitness of the musculoskeletal system in terms of satiation:
1. Cancer relapse.
2. Injury to the locomotor system.
3. Exacerbation of thromboembolism (including the antiphospholipid syndrome).
4. Pain in the area of the lumbar spine.
5. Root pain in the course of discopathy.
6. Cognitive dysfunction</exclusivecriteria>
  </eligibility>
  <trial_design>
    <studytype>Observational</studytype>
    <purpose />
    <allocation />
    <concealment />
    <sequence />
    <masking />
    <assignment />
    <designfeatures />
    <endpoint />
    <statisticalmethods>Apart from the graphical results, the analysis of the distribution of all variables will be assessed with the Shapiro-Wilk test. Basic descriptive statistics (arithmetic means and standard deviations) were assessed for the separated values of Peak min, t min, Peak max, t max and range of motion (ROM). The non-parametric Mann-Whitney U test was used to test the differences between sides and events for different angle profiles and SF functions (p = 0.05).</statisticalmethods>
    <masking1 />
    <masking2 />
    <masking3 />
    <masking4 />
    <patientregistry>False</patientregistry>
    <followup />
    <followuptype />
    <purposeobs>Natural history</purposeobs>
    <duration>Cross-sectional</duration>
    <selection>Case control</selection>
    <timing>Prospective</timing>
  </trial_design>
  <recruitment>
    <phase>Not Applicable</phase>
    <anticipatedstartdate />
    <actualstartdate>01/03/2019</actualstartdate>
    <anticipatedenddate />
    <actualenddate>31/10/2019</actualenddate>
    <samplesize>40</samplesize>
    <actualsamplesize>34</actualsamplesize>
    <currentsamplesize />
    <recruitmentstatus>Completed</recruitmentstatus>
    <anticipatedlastvisitdate />
    <actuallastvisitdate>30/04/2020</actuallastvisitdate>
    <dataanalysis />
    <withdrawnreason />
    <withdrawnreasonother />
    <recruitmentcountry>,Outside</recruitmentcountry>
    <recruitmentstate />
    <countryoutsideaustralia>
      <country>Poland</country>
      <state>Lower Silesia</state>
    </countryoutsideaustralia>
  </recruitment>
  <sponsorship>
    <primarysponsortype>University</primarysponsortype>
    <primarysponsorname>Wroclaw Medical University</primarysponsorname>
    <primarysponsoraddress>Wybrzeze L. Pasteura 1
50-367 Wroclaw</primarysponsoraddress>
    <primarysponsorcountry>Poland</primarysponsorcountry>
    <fundingsource>
      <fundingtype>University</fundingtype>
      <fundingname>Wroclaw Medical University</fundingname>
      <fundingaddress>Wybrzeze L. Pasteura 1
50-367 Wroclaw</fundingaddress>
      <fundingcountry>Poland</fundingcountry>
    </fundingsource>
    <secondarysponsor>
      <sponsortype>None</sponsortype>
      <sponsorname>None</sponsorname>
      <sponsoraddress>None</sponsoraddress>
      <sponsorcountry />
    </secondarysponsor>
  </sponsorship>
  <ethicsAndSummary>
    <summary>Assessment of gait symmetry is one of the main criteria for assessing the process of improving patients with various musculoskeletal disorders. In the case of patients after transfemoral amputation (TFA), gait parameters are evaluated by referring the obtained amputated data either to the whole limb or to the data of healthy people. Walking patterns in healthy people concerning time, distance, and vertical force are quite symmetrical, deviating in only a small percentage from ideal symmetry.  Numerous studies have demonstrated significant asymmetries in unilateral amputee gait. The underlying dissimilarities between prosthetic and intact limbs have not yet been widely examined. To gain more insight into the functionality of asymmetries, we propose a new tool, the symmetry function (SF), to evaluate the symmetry of walking in terms of kinematic and dynamic variables of patients after unilateral transfemoral amputation and to identify areas with the largest side deviations in the movement cycle. An instrumented motion analysis system was used to register the gait of fourteen patients after unilateral trans-femoral amputation. Measurements involved evaluating the time series of gait variables characterizing a range of motion and the time series of the ground reaction force components. </summary>
    <trialwebsite>None</trialwebsite>
    <publication>None</publication>
    <ethicsreview>Approved</ethicsreview>
    <publicnotes>None</publicnotes>
    <ethicscommitee>
      <ethicname>Bioethics Committee at the Medical University of Wroclaw</ethicname>
      <ethicaddress>ul. Pasul. Pasteura 1
50-367 Wroclaw</ethicaddress>
      <ethicapprovaldate>05/07/2012</ethicapprovaldate>
      <hrec>KB-612/2012</hrec>
      <ethicsubmitdate>01/05/2012</ethicsubmitdate>
      <ethiccountry>Poland</ethiccountry>
    </ethicscommitee>
  </ethicsAndSummary>
  <attachment />
  <contacts>
    <contact>
      <title>Dr</title>
      <name>Mateusz Kowal</name>
      <address>Department of Physiotherapy,  Medical University of Wroclaw 
Grunwaldzka Street 2 
50-355 Wroclaw</address>
      <phone>+48507197872</phone>
      <fax />
      <email>mateusz.kowal@umed.wroc.pl</email>
      <country>Poland</country>
      <type>Principal Investigator</type>
    </contact>
    <contact>
      <title>Dr</title>
      <name>Mateusz Kowal</name>
      <address>Department of Physiotherapy,  Medical University of Wroclaw 
Grunwaldzka Street 2 
50-355 Wroclaw</address>
      <phone>+48507197872</phone>
      <fax />
      <email>mateusz.kowal@umed.wroc.pl</email>
      <country>Poland</country>
      <type>Public Queries</type>
    </contact>
    <contact>
      <title>Dr</title>
      <name>Mateusz Kowal</name>
      <address>Department of Physiotherapy,  Medical University of Wroclaw 
Grunwaldzka Street 2 
50-355 Wroclaw</address>
      <phone>+48507197872</phone>
      <fax />
      <email>mateusz.kowal@umed.wroc.pl</email>
      <country>Poland</country>
      <type>Scientific Queries</type>
    </contact>
    <contact>
      <title />
      <name />
      <address />
      <phone />
      <fax />
      <email />
      <country />
      <type>Updating Information</type>
    </contact>
  </contacts>
  <dataSharing>
    <IPDsharing>Yes</IPDsharing>
    <data>Individual participant data underlying published results only.</data>
    <timeframe>Immediately following publication, no end date</timeframe>
    <availability>Only researchers who provide a methodologically sound proposal.</availability>
    <analysis>Only to achieve the aims in the approved proposal</analysis>
    <mechanism>Access subject to approvals by Principal Investigator (provide email: mateusz.kowal@umed.wroc.pl)</mechanism>
    <reason />
    <supportingDocuments>No other documents available</supportingDocuments>
  </dataSharing>
  <summaryResults>
    <journalPublications>0</journalPublications>
    <resultsReporting>https://www.anzctr.org.au/Steps11and12/379991-(Uploaded-28-07-2020-07-04-01)-Basic results summary.doc</resultsReporting>
    <resultsSummary>1 Research Question:The purpose of this study is to determine the relationship between torque values, torque symmetry of the hip flexor and extensor muscles of the intact and amputated limb, and the degree of gait asymmetry in transfemoral amputees (TFA).  Additional Objectives To evaluate gait symmetry in terms of changes in lower limb and pelvic joint ranges of motion (kinematic) and ground reaction force (dynamic) in patients following TFA.
2 Background Information:Assessment of gait symmetry is one of the main criteria for evaluating the motor rehabilitation process of patients with various musculoskeletal disorders. For patients with TFA, gait parameters are evaluated by relating the obtained amputation data to data for the whole limb or to data of healthy subjects.
3 Participant characteristics: Fourteen adults with unilateral TFA participated in the experiment.All participants underwent gait analysis, but only eight participated in the assessment of muscle torque acting on the hip joints. Six patients did not participate in the muscle torque assessment because their thigh stump was too short.
4 Key findings:This study showed consistent evidence of a significant association between hip extensors and gait asymmetry. The conclusions drawn from the mean value of the results obtained for the study group of patients with TFA are limited by errors due to multiple factors.
5 Limitations: Small number of subjects studied.</resultsSummary>
  </summaryResults>
</ANZCTR_Trial>
```

Each file contains data for a single clinical trial. In my folder have I have files for ~1000 clinical trials. I want to create a relational database where ANZCTR_Number is the primary key for all the tables. All the nodes which have children should make up a separate table.

What will be the approach for me to initiate this task.

I tried using the below code but it returns a long list. Each element of the list has multiple data frames. Not exactly what I wanted.

```
library(xml2relational)

all_files = list.files(pattern=".xml", path = getwd(), full.names = TRUE)
x = lapply(all_files, toRelational)
```

**Edit 1:**

I was trying to create a single dataframe. For that, I tried creating a function and applying it to sample files But got an error.

```
x_files <- function(x){
  data <- xmlParse(x)
  rootnode <- xmlRoot(data)
  ACTR_Number <- xmlValue(rootnode[[5]])
  Primary_sponsor_type <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[1]])
  Primary_sponsor_name <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[2]])
  Primary_sponsor_address <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[3]])
  Primary_sponsor_country <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[4]])
  Funding_type <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[5]][[1]])
  Funding_name <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[5]][[2]])
  Funding_address <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[5]][[3]])
  Funding_country <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[5]][[4]])
  Secondary_sponsor_type <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[6]][[1]])
  Secondary_sponsor_name <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[6]][[2]])
  Secondary_sponsor_address <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[6]][[3]])
  Secondary_sponsor_country <- xmlValue(rootnode[[13]][[6]][[4]])
  
}

#COde to access the bulk XML files from a directory

dat_files = list.files(path = "E:/My_projects/test",
                       recursive = T,
                       pattern = ".xml",
                       full.names = T)
##------
library(purrr)

df = map_df(dat_files, x_files)
```

***ANY KIND OF HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED***

Comment: "All the nodes which have children should make up a separate table." It's not at all clear what structure you are trying to create. If you put this into first normal form then it looks to me like you'll need at least a dozen tables.

Comment: By table, I mean...a dataframe.

Comment: OK, I thought I knew what relational databases and tables were. It seems both terms have been hijacked.